# FirebaseのGoogleのユーザー認証で特定の数人のみ許可する方法

Tags: firebase, 認証認可

Firebaseを使ったAuthenticationで一般ユーザーをGoogleアカウントで扱う方法はすぐにわかったのですが、
事前に許可した特定のGmailアドレスの持ち主のみをGoogleのOAuthで認証させる方法が見つかりませんでした。

できればGoogleアカウントでのログイン処理をしたいのですが、
難しいようであればそれ以外の方法でも構いません。

Firebaseで一般ユーザーは閲覧のみ、管理者ユーザーは事前登録した数人のみが使えるという設定にするにはどうすればよいのでしょうか？

こちらの本家の解説によると
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17607101/firebase-authenticate-as-admin

`signInWithCustomToken`もしくは、こちらが`deprecated`なので`signInAndRetrieveDataWithCustomToken`を使うと良さそうなのですが、カスタムトークンの解説を読んでも特定のユーザーのみ許可する方法がわからず詰まっています。

どうすれば事前に設定したユーザーにだけログインを許可することができるでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

「認証は出来るけどデータ取得等ができないようにする」と問題を読み替えることは可能ですか？
であれば，データベース等のセキュリティルールを設定することで実現は容易です．